# Using Numpy Vectorize on Functions that Return Vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

`numpy.vectorize` takes a function f:a->b and turns it into g:a[]->b[].

This works fine when `a` and `b` are scalars, but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work with b as an `ndarray` or list, i.e. f:a->b[] and g:a[]->b[][]

For example:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return x * np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32)
g = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.ndarray])
a = np.arange(4)
print(g(a))
```

This yields:

```
array([[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.],
       [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.],
       [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.],
       [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]], dtype=object)
```

Ok, so that gives the right values, but the wrong dtype.  And even worse:

```
g(a).shape
```

yields:

```
(4,)
```

So this array is pretty much useless.  I know I can convert it doing:

```
np.array(map(list, a), dtype=np.float32)
```

to give me what I want:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]], dtype=float32)
```

but that is neither efficient nor pythonic.  Can any of you guys find a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work as you expect, is that you pass `otypes=[np.ndarray]`. So your result is an array with elements which are arrays thus you get the `dtype=object`. You specifically asked for it.

Answer (score 73):

`np.vectorize` is just a convenience function. It doesn't actually [make code run any faster](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg00587.html). If it isn't convenient to use `np.vectorize`, simply write your own function that works as you wish.

The purpose of `np.vectorize` is to transform functions which are not numpy-aware (e.g. take floats as input and return floats as output) into functions that can operate on (and return) numpy arrays.

Your function `f` is already numpy-aware -- it uses a numpy array in its definition and returns a numpy array. So `np.vectorize` is not a good fit for your use case.

The solution therefore is just to roll your own function `f` that works the way you desire.

Comment: Indeed, "just a convenience function" describes most of the numpy API. That's the whole point.  It's too bad this function doesn't behave like one would expect.

Comment: Most NumPy functions are just a bit slower than the equivalent function written in C. This is true when the NumPy function is merely a thin wrapper around a C (or Fortran) function. In contrast, a `np.vectorized` function still has to call a *Python function* once for each element in the array, so it performs more like Python code than C code. Python's dynamic name lookups provides more flexibility, but can be much much slower than C code.

Comment: not according to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array

Answer (score 33):

A new parameter `signature` in 1.12.0 does exactly what you what.

```
def f(x):
    return x * np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32)

g = np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(n)')
```

Then `g(np.arange(4)).shape` will give `(4L, 5L)`.

Here the signature of `f` is specified. The `(n)` is the shape of the return value, and the `()` is the shape of the parameter which is scalar. And the parameters can be arrays too. For more complex signatures, see [Generalized Universal Function API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return x * np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32)
g = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.ndarray])
a = np.arange(4)
b = g(a)
b = np.array(b.tolist())
print(b)#b.shape = (4,5)
c = np.ones((2,3,4))
d = g(c)
d = np.array(d.tolist())
print(d)#d.shape = (2,3,4,5)
```

This should fix the problem and it will work regardless of what size your input is. "map" only works for one dimentional inputs. Using ".tolist()" and creating a new ndarray solves the problem more completely and nicely(I believe). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to vectorize the function

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return x * np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32)
```

Assuming that you want to get single `np.float32` arrays as result, you have to specify this as `otype`. In your question you specified however `otypes=[np.ndarray]` which means you want every element to be an `np.ndarray`. Thus, you correctly get a result of `dtype=object`.

The correct call would be

```
np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(n)', otypes=[np.float32])
```

For such a simple function it is however better to leverage `numpy`'s ufunctions; `np.vectorize` just loops over it. So in your case just rewrite your function as

```
def f(x):
    return np.multiply.outer(x, np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32))
```

This is faster and produces less obscure errors (note however, that the results `dtype` will depend on `x` if you pass a complex or quad precision number, so will be the result).

Answer (score 1):

I've written a function, it seems fits to your need.

```
def amap(func, *args):
    '''array version of build-in map
    amap(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> array
    Examples
    --------
    >>> amap(lambda x: x**2, 1)
    array(1)
    >>> amap(lambda x: x**2, [1, 2])
    array([1, 4])
    >>> amap(lambda x,y: y**2 + x**2, 1, [1, 2])
    array([2, 5])
    >>> amap(lambda x: (x, x), 1)
    array([1, 1])
    >>> amap(lambda x,y: [x**2, y**2], [1,2], [3,4])
    array([[1, 9], [4, 16]])
    '''
    args = np.broadcast(None, *args)
    res = np.array([func(*arg[1:]) for arg in args])
    shape = args.shape + res.shape[1:]
    return res.reshape(shape)
```

Let try

```
def f(x):
        return x * np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.float32)
amap(f, np.arange(4))
```

Outputs

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]], dtype=float32)
```

You may also wrap it with lambda or partial for convenience

```
g = lambda x:amap(f, x)
g(np.arange(4))
```

---

Note the docstring of `vectorize` says

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
>   performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Thus we would expect the `amap` here have similar performance as `vectorize`. I didn't check it, Any performance test are welcome.

If the performance is really important, you should consider something else, e.g. direct array calculation with `reshape` and `broadcast` to avoid loop in pure python (both `vectorize` and `amap` are the later case).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be to use a 2-D NumPy array (in this case a column array) as an input to the *original* function, which will then generate a 2-D output with the results I believe you were expecting.

Here is what it might look like in code:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return x*np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=np.float32)

a = np.arange(4).reshape((4, 1))
b = f(a)
# b is a 2-D array with shape (4, 5)
print(b)
```

This is a much simpler and less error prone way to complete the operation.  Rather than trying to transform the function with numpy.vectorize, this method relies on NumPy's natural ability to broadcast arrays.  The trick is to make sure that at least one dimension has an equal length between the arrays.