# NumPy thinks a 2-D array is 1-D

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array that is constructed from a text file.  I've been doing things this way for weeks and never seen this problem before.

```
print data
print data[:, 1:]
```

outputs

```
[['1', '200', '300', '400', '500\n']
 ['3', '500', '400', '200', '1000\n']
 ['14', '900', '200', '300', '100\n'] ...,
 ['999142', '24', '21', '20', '12\n']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ...., line ..., in ....
print data[:, 1:]
IndexError:  too many indices
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Edit:  Big clue.  `data.shape` is `(3313869,)` with no second value.

`data.ndim` is `1`.

`len(data[1])`, however, is 5.

Edit, I am constructing it with

```
data = [re.split(' ', line) for line in f]
f.close()
data = np.array(data)
```

When I interject

```
f.close()
print data[0:10]
```

It gives i.e.

`[['1', '200', '300', '400', '500\n'], ['3', .... ]]`

Comment: Can you provide us with simple code that we could use to reproduce this?  It would make your question much more clear...

Comment: this error would occur if your array was a 1D array, you can check that doing `array.shape`

Comment: could you ask for `data.ndim`?

Comment: See edit, it's 1.  I am so confused.

Comment: And the size=3313869 would not be possible for a 2D array with 5 columns, the size should be a multiple of 5... there is probably something wrong

Comment: .. could you print the results of `set(map(len, data))`?  I suspect that what's going on is that your input data is ragged (there's a line, maybe at the end, which doesn't have the same number of elements) and so `numpy` is doing the best it can, and giving you a one-dimensional array with object dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happened because your code is somehow creating a `numpy.array` of objects. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3379301/832621) with a similar issue. When it happens you get something like:

```
a = numpyp.array([list1, list2, list3, ... , listn], dtype=object)
```

It is a 1D array, but when you ask to print it will call the `__str__` of each list inside, giving:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [ 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

which seems like a 2D array.

You can simulate it doing:

```
a = ['aaa' for i in range(10)]
b = numpy.empty((5),dtype=object)
b.fill(a)
```

lets check `b`:

```
b.shape # (5,)
b.ndim  # 1
```

but `print b` gives:

```
[['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
 ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
 ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
 ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
 ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']]
```

Quite tricky...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with

```
for line in data:
          if (len(line) != 5):
                  print len(line)
                  print line
```

A few of the lines in my data had spaces at the end, which was leading to `500` and `\n` being separated into separate tokens.  This snuck in because on Friday, the last time I messed with this code, I had added in a default option to the Python script that builds the input files for this script for rows that were missing a particular value, and Vim put in a space token on the line-wrap, which just happened to be on the character right before `\n`.

`[re.split(' ', line.replace('\n', '').rstrip()) for line in f]` gives the desires result.

It is a little strange, I think, that NumPy treats the array as both 1-D and 2-D (allowing me to select `data[1]` as a row) but I guess if the rows aren't of consistent length it just sees it as an array of arrays rather than a 2-D array, making a distinction between the two.

Comment: If you are using numpy to store strings you might want to rethink what you are using numpy for.  numpy was only optimized for floats and integers; you probably won't see much advantage with numpy for string manipulations.