# Can Numpy's frompyfunc() return an image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to build a NxN grid in the complex plane, and assign each point z in this grid a RGB color according to some rule f(z).

For example, the grid z is

```
x,y = numpy.ogrid[-1:1:N*1j,-1:1:N*1j]
z = x+y*1j
```

and the function setcolor() is

```
def setcolor(z):
    return (r,g,b) triple of z according to some rule
```

My problem occurs when I was going to display the image of f(z) with numpy's frompyfunc():

```
img = numpy.frompyfunc(setcolor,1,1)(z).astype(np.float)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The resulting imag is all blue (by default colormap 'jet'), no error nor warning, so it's obvious that imshow() has turned all (r,g,b) triple into a single float maybe 1 (or 0). I guess this is because of the astype(np.float) option, but it seems this is the only reasonable option.

Of course one can use two for loops to display img:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        img[i,j] = f(z[i,j])
```

but this is not very efficient(my own opinion). I want to use the fromptfunc() directly.

So how I can display this image with frompyfunc()?

Comment: `frompyfunc` wont speed up your code ... just so you know

Comment: What does `numpy.frompyfunc(setcolor,1,1)(z)` look like (for small `N`)?  `frompyfunc`, if working, might give as much as a 2x speed up, but nothing like a genuine vectorization.

Comment: [`numpy.frompyfunc` seems to have issues with functions that already return sequences.](http://ideone.com/dPhCR9) Looks like it might be a NumPy bug. You probably shouldn't be using `frompyfunc` anyway, though.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I compared the frompyfunc() and  the "for loops", the former is significantly faster than the latter. May be there is some other way to speed up the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [588]: x,y=np.ogrid[-1:1:5*1j,-1:1:5*1j]
In [589]: z=x*y*1j
In [590]: def setcolor(z):
    return (z.real,z.imag,np.abs(z))
   .....: 
In [591]: fn=np.frompyfunc(setcolor,1,1)
In [592]: fn(z)
Out[592]: 
array([[None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

which turns to an array of 0s with `.astype(float)`.  Here `setcolor` is just a simple way of getting 3 numbers from a complex input.  You can choose something more realistic.

But if we give it the correct `out` count, we get a tuple of arrays.

```
In [593]: fn=np.frompyfunc(setcolor,1,3)
In [594]: fn(z)
Out[594]: 
(array([[0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0],
        [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object),
 array([[1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, -1.0],
        [0.5, 0.25, 0.0, -0.25, -0.5],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [-0.5, -0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5],
        [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0]], dtype=object),
 array([[1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        [0.5, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.5, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5],
        [1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0]], dtype=object))
```

It could be turned in to a (3,N,N) array with:

```
np.array([A.astype(float) for A in fn(z)])
```

You'd have to do a transpose to make a (N,N,3) array.

For this small sample it isn't faster

```
In [599]: timeit np.array([A.astype(float) for A in fn(z)]).transpose([1,2,0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 664 µs per loop

In [603]: %%timeit 
   .....: img=np.zeros((5,5,3),float)
   .....: for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        img[i,j]=setcolor(z[i,j])
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 316 µs per loop
```

In some other SO questions I found that `frompyfunc` is faster than `vectorize`, and a modest improvement over direct iteration.

This is faster - but it doesn't do the job

```
In [606]: timeit np.frompyfunc(setcolor,1,1)(z).astype(float)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 µs per loop
```

The `setcolor` that I chose can take the array `z` directly, resulting in a fast 3d array creation.

```
In [608]: timeit np.array([A.astype(float) for A in setcolor(z)]).transpose([1,2,0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 µs per loop
```

---

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703463/901925, an earlier answer involving `frompystack`, I find that `vstack` is a faster way to assemble a tuple into a 3d array:

```
In [616]: timeit np.vstack(fn(z)).astype(float).reshape(3,5,5).transpose([1,2,0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 µs per loop
```

So done right, `frompyfunc` can give about a 2x speedup over explicit iteration, but still not as good as function that handles arrays directly.

Answer (score 0):

I left out the (rgb) tuple which is separate from the main question, on how to make an efficient assignment with `numpy`. The magic is all in using `meshgrid`:

```
import pylab as p
import numpy as np 

f= lambda z :  np.cos(z)  # example

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
xn, yn = X.shape
W = np.zeros_like(X)

for x in range(xn):
    for y in range(yn):
        z = complex(X[x,y],Y[x,y])
        w = float(f(z))
        W[x,y] = w

p.imshow(W)
```

[image]