# Apply a function to the 0-dimension of an ndarray

Tags: python, function, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

### Problem

- I have an `ndarray`, defined by `arr` that is an `n`-dimensional cube with length `m` in each dimension.
- I want to act a function, `func`, by slicing along the dimension `n=0` and taking each `n-1`-dim slice as an input to the function.

This seems to work for `map()` but I can't find a `numpy` variant that is appropriate. `np.vectorise` seems to split the `n-1`-tensor into individual scalar entries. Neither `apply_along_axis` or `apply_over_axes` seem appropriate either.

My problem is such that I need to pass arbitrary functions as inputs so I do not see a solution with `einsum` being feasible either.

### Question

- Do you know the best `numpy` alternative to using `np.asarray(map(func, arr))`?

### Example

I define an example array, `arr` as a `4`-dim cube (or 4-tensor) by:

```
m, n = 3, 4 
arr = np.arange(m**n).reshape((m,)*n)
```

I define an example function `f`,

```
def f(x):
    """makes it obvious how the np.ndarray is being passed into the function"""
    try: # perform an op using x[0,0,0] which is expected to exist
        i = x[0,0,0]
    except:
        print '\nno element x[0,0,0] in x: \n{}'.format(x)
        return np.nan
    return x-x+i
```

The expected result, `res`, from this function would remain the same shape but would satisfy the following:

```
print all([(res[i] == i*m**(n-1)).all() for i in range(m)])
```

This works with the default `map()` function,

```
res = np.asarray(map(f, a))
print all([(res[i] == i*m**(n-1)).all() for i in range(m)])
True
```

I would expect `np.vectorize` to work in the same way as `map()` but it acts in scalar entries:

```
res = np.vectorize(f)(a)

no element x[0,0,0] in x: 
0
...
```

Comment: related but not solving the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3379301/4013571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `arr` is 4d, and your `fn` works on 3d arrays,

```
np.asarray(map(func, arr))   # list(map(...)) for Py3
```

looks perfectly reasonable.  I'd use the list comprehension form, but that's a matter of programming style

```
np.asarray([func(i) for i in arr])
```

`for i in arr` iterates on the first dimension of `arr`.  In effect it treats `arr` as a list of the 3d arrays.  And then it reassembles the resulting list into a 4d array.

`np.vectorize` doc could be more explicit about the function taking scalars.  But yes, it passes values as scalars.  Note that `np.vectorize` does not have provision for passing an iteration axis parameter.  It's most useful when your function takes values from several array, something like

```
 [func(a,b) for a,b in zip(arrA, arrB)]
```

It generalizes the `zip` so allow for broadcasting.  But otherwise it is an iterative solution.  It knows nothing about the guts of your `func`, so it can't speed up its calls.

`np.vectorize` ends up calling `np.frompyfunc`, which being a bit less general is a bit faster.  But it too passes scalars to the func.

`np.apply_along/over_ax(e/i)s` also iterate over one or more axes.  You may find their code instructive, but I agree they don't apply here.

A variation on the map approach is to allocate the result array, and index:

```
In [45]: res=np.zeros_like(arr,int)
In [46]: for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    ...:     res[i,...] = f(arr[i,...])
```

This may be easier if you need to iterate on a different axis than the 1st.

You need to do your own timings to see which is faster.

========================

An example of iteration over the 1st dimension with in-place modification:

```
In [58]: arr.__array_interface__['data']  # data buffer address
Out[58]: (152720784, False)

In [59]: for i,a in enumerate(arr):
    ...:     print(a.__array_interface__['data'])
    ...:     a[0,0,:]=i
    ...:     
(152720784, False)   # address of the views (same buffer)
(152720892, False)
(152721000, False)

In [60]: arr
Out[60]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        ...

       [[[ 1,  1,  1],
         [30, 31, 32],
         ...

       [[[ 2,  2,  2],
         [57, 58, 59],
         [60, 61, 62]],
       ...]]])
```

When I iterate over an array, I get a view that starts at successive points on the common data buffer.  If I modify the view, as above or even with `a[:]=...`, I modify the original.  I don't have to write anything back.  But don't use `a = ....`, which breaks the link to the original array.

Comment: the problem with `map()` and generator expressions is that the reallocate memory locations for the `ndarray` which is wasteful for large arrays - I was hoping there was a `numpy` function that would just use the existing memory pointers to the current array locations

Comment: `arr[i,...] = f(arr[i,...])` will put the subarrays back in the original array.  Whether temporary arrays, copies or views are created depends on the details of what `f` is doing.  But I wonder how well you understand the use of `memory pointers` in numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I would say I understand better than most but probably average-low among python experts - [this book](http://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/numpybook.pdf#153) got me most of the way, particularly section 2.3 and 3.1.1

Comment: I'll try to write an example of `f` that modifies its input `x` in-place and doesn't the last assignment

Comment: thanks - I'm manipulating lattices of sizes up to `48**4` or possibly even `48**7` but the latter I will probably use `C` or `Fortran` instead so memory usage is worthwhile thinking about even if it's just a comment in my code as a reminder

Comment: I added a simple inplace modification of the array.