# Broadcasting error when vectorizing misc.imresize()

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array A composed of multiple same sized images [N_images,width,height,3].

I want to apply `misc.imresize()` to each and everyone of them the fastest way possible.

So I defined:

```
def myfunc(x):
  return misc.imresize(x,(wanted_width,wanted_height))
```

and then I did:

```
vfunc=np.vectorize(my_func)
```

but when I try:

```
test=vfunc(A)
```

I get a not-suitable-array-shape-for-converting-into-images error. 
I thought it was because I did not specify the axis on which the op should be vectorized, which caused it to not broadcast the array ops the way to wanted so I tried another thing to narrow down the error:

```
test=np.apply_along_axis(my_func,0,A)
```

and got the same error. 
Even if I force a np.squeeze() into my_func. That really surprised me.

**EDIT:** I also tried with `map` same error.
It might stem from the fact that you can only use vectorize with scalar function as pointed out by @jotasi.

It must be pretty silly but I do not know what is going on. Could somebody enlighten me ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not have an `axis` parameter as it is only meant to be used for functions that are not numpy aware and take scalars. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379505/6614295) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that ! So should I give up trying to vectorize it or is there some other ways ?

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy way to avoid doing some kind of loop, as `misc.imresize` also does not support a vectorized application along an axis. If your image is large enough, I'd guess, that a loop should not represent a bottleneck anyway.

Comment: Ok I will close my question tomorrow if there is a consensus.

Comment: Yes. Definitively, I also might be mistaken. Let's see if someone else comes up with something.

Comment: If speed is your motivation then `np.vectorize` is unlikely to help. [*"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: Thanks @ali_m I did not know that at all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative *vectorized* approach using scipy's [zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom). However, it is not necessarily faster for small amount of images (e.g. for N=100 a loop might be faster).

```
>>> from skimage import color, util, data
>>> img = util.img_as_float(color.gray2rgb(data.camera())) # Sample RGB image
```

I did just replicate a gray-scale image over the RGB channels, so it will still look gray-scale, but it is RGB in practice.

Create 100 RGB images by replicating above RGB image and its horizontal flip (to ensure interpolation is working properly).

```
>>> data = np.empty((100,) + img.shape, img.dtype)
>>> data[0::2] = img
>>> data[1::2] = img[:,::-1]
>>> plt.imshow(data[50])
```

[image]

Find zooming factors:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import zoom
>>> new_size = (200, 200)
>>> fy, fx = np.asarray(new_size, np.float32) / data.shape[1:3]
```

Resize image, factor of `1` means no interpolation over that axis:

```
>>> resized = zoom(data, (1, fy, fx, 1), order=0) # order=0 for quicker
>>> plt.imshow(resized[50]) # resized.shape = (100, 200, 200, 3)
```

[image]

Again, be aware that although it is a vectorized version, it uses NN interpolation in order to be *quick*, a standard loop + arbitrary interpolation might be way faster. Take this as a proof of concept and have a look if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I upvoted it. I am gonna benchmark it for my implementation and see what comes out.

Comment: But I don't really care about the kind of interpolation as long as the images look ok and I have around 500000 images so it might be indeed faster.

Comment: I cannot use NN interpolation the artefacts are too important for my application and when I push the order of the spline to 1 there is no speed up.

Comment: @jean No problem! Thanks for the feedback, I didn't actually benchmark the approach.

Comment: The fact that it is not faster (or maybe even slower) is because, even if it just does 2D+color interpolation in practice, the function is trying to perform a 4D interpolation. The factor set to `1` prevents those axis from being interpolated, but I'm pressuming it has to do that check every time. Or in other words, N times 2D+color interpolation is better optimized than the above N-D interpolation with constrains.