# How does the numpy.resize and numpy.reshape function works internally in python ?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

In the package numpy their are two function resize and reshape. How internally they work? What kind of interpolation does they use ?I looked into the code, but didnt get it. Can anyone help me out. Or how does an image get resized. What happens with its pixels ?

Comment: from the docs:If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html

Comment: Neither `np.resize` nor `np.reshape` are at all suitable for image resizing. Numpy is about arrays, not images.

Answer (score 7):

Neither interpolates.  And if you are wondering about interpolation and pixels of an image, they probably aren't the functions that you want.  There some `image` packages (e.g in `scipy`) that manipulate the resolution of images.

Every `numpy` array has a `shape` attribute.  `reshape` just changes that, without changing the data at all.  The new shape has to reference the same total number of elements as the original shape.

```
 x = np.arange(12)
 x.reshape(3,4)    # 12 elements
 x.reshape(6,2)    # still 12
 x.reshape(6,4)    # error
```

`np.resize` is less commonly used, but is written in Python and available for study.  You have to read its docs, and `x.resize` is different.  Going larger it actually repeats values or pads with zeros.

examples of resize acting in 1d:

```
In [366]: x=np.arange(12)
In [367]: np.resize(x,6)
Out[367]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [368]: np.resize(x,24)
Out[368]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
        5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [369]: x.resize(24)
In [370]: x
Out[370]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

A recent question about `scipy.misc.imresize`.  It also references `scipy.ndimage.zoom`:

[Broadcasting error when vectorizing misc.imresize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159997/broadcasting-error-when-vectorizing-misc-imresize)

Comment: _"reshape just changes [`.shape`]"_ - more accurately, it creates a view with that changed, rather than actually modifying the object it is called on

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `numpy.reshape()` just reshapes a matrix (does not matter if it is an image or not). It does not do any interpolation and just manipulates the items in a matrix.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape((2,6))


a= [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]]


b=a.reshape((4,3))

b=[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]
```