# What is the difference between resize and reshape when using arrays in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have just started using NumPy. What is the difference between `resize` and `reshape` for arrays?

Comment: Have you tried any research?

Comment: ```sum(ndarray.shape)``` and ```ndarray.size``` are the same after ```ndarray.reshape```.  Those values will be different after ```ndarray.resize```

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, but it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171034/how-does-the-numpy-resize-and-numpy-reshape-function-works-internally-in-python

Answer (score 28):

Reshape doesn't change the data as mentioned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
Resize changes the data as can be seen [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html).

Here are some examples:

```
>>> numpy.random.rand(2,3)
array([[ 0.6832785 ,  0.23452056,  0.25131171],
       [ 0.81549186,  0.64789272,  0.48778127]])
>>> ar = numpy.random.rand(2,3)
>>> ar.reshape(1,6)
array([[ 0.43968751,  0.95057451,  0.54744355,  0.33887095,  0.95809916,
         0.88722904]])
>>> ar
array([[ 0.43968751,  0.95057451,  0.54744355],
       [ 0.33887095,  0.95809916,  0.88722904]])
```

After reshape the array didn't change, but only output a temporary array reshape.

```
>>> ar.resize(1,6)
>>> ar
array([[ 0.43968751,  0.95057451,  0.54744355,  0.33887095,  0.95809916,
         0.88722904]])
```

After resize the array changed its shape.

Comment: since OP did not specify, i'll point out that `ar.resize(rows,cols)` changes the initial array in-place, while `np.resize(ar,X)` only outputs a resized array, with `ar` staying the same.
Also, if the new size is larger than original `ar`, `ar.resize` adds zeroes at the end, while `np.resize` repeats the original `ar`

Answer (score 10):

One major difference is **reshape() does not change your data, but resize() does** change it. resize() first accommodates all the values in the original array. After that, if extra space is there (or size of new array is greater than original array), it adds its own values. As @David mentioned in comments, what values resize() adds depends on how that is called.

You can call `reshape()` and `resize()` function in the following two ways.

`numpy.resize()`

`ndarray.resize()` - where `ndarray` is an `n` dimensional array you are resizing.

You can similarly call reshape also as `numpy.reshape()` and `ndarray.reshape()`. But here they are almost the same except the syntax.

One point to notice is that, **reshape() will always try to return a view wherever possible, otherwise it would return a copy**. Also, it can't tell what will be returned when, but you can make your code to raise error whenever the data is copied.

For resize() function, **`numpy.resize()` returns a new copy of the array whereas `ndarray.resize()` does it in-place. But they don't go to the `view` thing.**

Now coming to the point that what the values of extra elements should be. From the documentation, it says

> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a. Note that this behavior is different from a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of repeated copies of a.

So for `ndarray.resize()` it is the value `0`, but for `numpy.resize()` it is the values of the array itself (of course, whatever can fit in the new size). The below code snippet will make it clear.

```
In [40]: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [41]: np.resize(arr, (2,5))
Out[41]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
      [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]])

In [42]: arr.resize((2,5))

In [43]: arr
Out[43]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You can also see that `ndarray.resize()` returns `None` and does the resizing in-place.

Answer (score 8):

1. `reshape()` is able to change the *shape only (i.e. the meta info),* **not** the number of elements.

   If the array has five elements, we may use e.g. `reshape(5, )`, `reshape(1, 5)`,
   `reshape(1, 5, 1)`, but **not** `reshape(2, 3)`.

   - `reshape()` in general don't modify data themselves, only *meta info about them,*
   - the `.reshape()` **method** (of ndarray) returns the reshaped array, *keeping the original array untouched.*
2. `resize()` is able to change both the shape and the number of elements, too.

   So for an array with five elements we may use `resize(5, 1)`, but also `resize(2, 2)` or `resize(7, 9)`.

   - The `.resize()` **method** (of ndarray) returns `None`, changing *only the original array* (so it seems as an *in-place change*).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following np.ndarray:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) # Shape of this is (4,)
```

Now we try 'a.reshape'

```
a.reshape(1, 4)

array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])

a.shape         # This will again return (4,)
```

We see that the shape of `a` hasn't changed.

Let's try 'a.resize' now:

```
a.resize(1,4)

a.shape         # Now the shape changes to (1,4)
```

'resize' changed the shape of our original NumPy array a (It changes shape 'IN-PLACE').

Answer (score 0):

One more point is:

*np.reshape* can take -1 in one dimension. *np.resize* can't.

Example as below:

```
arr = np.arange(20)
arr.resize(5, 2, 2)
arr.reshape(2, 2, -1)
```