# Reshaping images for Conv2D model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am building a classifier for binary classification, when I try to reshape the images into the proper input types for the model I am getting this error.

```
 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 25000 into shape (50,50,3) ----- BGR
```

However it works perfectly fine when I am reshaping images which are GrayScale.

```
X=np.array(x).reshape(-1,50,50,1)
```

This is how I am loading and resizing the images:

```
training_data=[]
labels=[]
for i in os.listdir():
    label=i.split('.')[0]
    if label=='cat':
       labels.append(0)
    else:
       labels.append(1)
    
    image=cv2.imread(i)
    image_array=cv2.resize(image,(50,50))
    training_data.append([image,labels])
```

Comment: `image.shape` gives ??

Comment: reshape and resize aren't the same thing. You can't reshape a matrix of `50 x 50 x 3 = 7500` to `25000`. You've not shown where reshape is used on the 'image' in your code. This link can also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518430/1836069