# Vectorized function returning a list of vectors in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to write a function in Python that takes an list of parameters `a` as an input and returns a list of vectors `u` that depend on these parameters. I would then like to be able to act on `u` with standard vector operations (such as the scalar product). In the example below (inspired from the second answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors)), the function returns a combination of two initial vectors `v` and `w`:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1,0,0])
w = np.array([0,1,0])
a = np.linspace(0,np.pi,4)
def u(a):
   u = np.cos(a)*v + np.sin(a)*w
   return u  
uvec = np.vectorize(u, otypes=[np.ndarray])    
ufin = np.array(uvec(a).tolist())
print "ufin =", ufin
print "ufin.v =", np.dot(ufin,v)
```

This returns:

```
ufin = [[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.00000000e-01   8.66025404e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -5.00000000e-01   8.66025404e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -1.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   0.00000000e+00]]
ufin.v = [ 1.   0.5 -0.5 -1. ]
```

which is what I wanted to obtain since `ufin` behaves like a vector. Could you tell me if there are other simpler ways of realizing this? I need to write a code where numerous vectors and vector operations have to be defined and would like it to be as compact as possible.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit:**

I found another (apparently more compact) solution based on the last answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors). The idea is to reshape the list of parameters into a column array such that the output of the function automatically (without the need for vectorization) returns a list of vectors as a 2-D array. This is done in this way:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

v = np.array([1,0,0])
w = np.array([0,1,0])
a = np.linspace(0,np.pi,4).reshape((4,1))
b = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,4).reshape((4,1))
def u(a):
   u = np.cos(a)*v + np.sin(a)*w
   return u 
print "u(a) =",u(a)
print "u(b) =",u(b) 
print "u(a).v =",np.dot(u(a),v)
print "u(a)^v =",np.cross(u(a),v)
# print "u(a).u(b) =",np.dot(u(a),u(b)) # does not work
print "u(a).u(b) =",inner1d(u(a),u(b)) # works
print "u(a)^u(b) =",np.cross(u(a),u(b))
```

This returns:

```
u(a) = [[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.00000000e-01   8.66025404e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -5.00000000e-01   8.66025404e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -1.00000000e+00   1.22464680e-16   0.00000000e+00]]
u(b) = [[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  8.66025404e-01   5.00000000e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.00000000e-01   8.66025404e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.12323400e-17   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
u(a).v = [ 1.   0.5 -0.5 -1. ]
u(a)^v = [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.66025404e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.66025404e-01]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.22464680e-16]]
u(a).u(b) = [  1.00000000e+00   8.66025404e-01   5.00000000e-01   6.12323400e-17]
u(a)^u(b) = [[ 0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.        -0.5      ]
 [ 0.         0.        -0.8660254]
 [ 0.         0.        -1.       ]]
```

which is the correct behavior both for operations involving the initial (`u` and `v`) and the output lists of vectors (`u(a)` and `u(b)`) and for operations involving the two output lists of vectors. The only caveat (for operations between the output list of vectors) is that the `inner1d` function has to be used instead of the standard `np.dot` because the latter is interpreted as a matrix product which cannot be done since the two matrices have inconsistent sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't object to obtaining a 2d array instead of an array of objects (the former is more convenient than the latter for most uses, anyway) then the *outer product* is useful for this problem:

```
>>> np.outer(np.cos(a), v) + np.outer(np.sin(a), w)
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00]])
>>> _ @ v
array([ 1. ,  0.5, -0.5, -1. ])
```

The `@` infix operator is only available on python 3.5 or later. In older versions you can use `np.dot`. The meaning of either in this context is [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I edited my initial post with a more compact version based on reshaping the list of parameters into a column array. Could you let me know which method you think is most suitable?

Comment: Is there no standard way (such as a library of functions) of performing these types of operations with Python? Such operations are very common in the treatment of physics problems (for example, plotting the angular momentum of orbits as a function of the orbital parameters) so I would be surprised if this is the case.

Comment: @user3450569 Yes, in this case (where your function happens to be "vector-ready") your solution is a bit more elegant. You could also write `a = np.linspace(0,np.pi,4)[:, None]` to get the column vector which I personally find a bit easier on the eye; but that is a matter of taste. You may want to have a look at `np.ogrid` and `np.ix_` which are useful in similar situations.

Comment: @user3450569 But you are using library functions. How short does it have to be to satisfy you? ;-) For example the if you have three, say, parameter vectors `p1, p2, p3` and you want to run through all combinations then you could simply do `a1, a2, a3 = np.ix_(p1, p2, p3) and call your 3-parameter array-aware function on that.

Answer (score 0):

So you are telling `vectorze` that the function `u` returns an array, or actually an `object`, since there isn't a `dtype=array`.

```
In [475]: uvec=np.vectorize(u, otypes=[object])
In [476]: uvec(a)
Out[476]: 
array([array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
       array([-0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
       array([ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00])], dtype=object)
```

So if you want to 'unravel' that and create a 2d array you have to convert it to a list of arrays, and then use `np.array` or (`np.stack`) to join them along a new dimension:

```
In [477]: uvec(a).tolist()
Out[477]: 
[array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
 array([-0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
 array([ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00])]
```

But for iteration on a single 1d array like `a`, `vectorize` is over-kill.  A simple list comprehension works just as well

```
In [483]: np.array([u(i) for i in a])
Out[483]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00]]
```

`vectorize` is more useful when there are several input arrays, and they can have several dimensions.  It takes care of broadcasting and iterating over multiple levels.  You could have also used `np.frompyfunc(u,1,1)`, which always returns an object array, and is slightly faster.

But you can also calculate this without looping:

```
def ufunc(a,v,w):
    a = a[:,None]
    return np.cos(a)*v + np.sin(a)*w

In [498]: ufunc(a,v,w)
Out[498]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

This turns `a` into a (4,1) array which broadcasts against the `(3,)` `v` to produce a `(4,3)` array.

---

Another approach is to define a function that takes scalars (all around)

```
import math
def u1(a,v,w):
    return math.cos(a)*v+math.sin(a)*w
u1v = np.vectorize(u1, otypes=[float])

In [505]: u1v(a[:,None], v, w)
Out[505]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -5.00000000e-01,   8.66025404e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

This takes advantage of the full broadcasting ability of `vectorize`. I though it would be slower than your code because it has to loop in both dimensions, but it actually tests faster (though not as fast as my `ufunc`).  Trying to half vectorize the `u` function might not buy you any speed.

---

You could have also defined your original function to take `v` and `w` as arguments, and use the `vectorize` `excluded` parameter to pass them as is.  I don't think it has a performance benefit.

```
In [521]: def u2(a,v,w):
     ...:     return np.cos(a)*v + np.sin(a)*w
     ...: 
In [522]: u2vec=np.vectorize(u2, otypes=[object],excluded=[1,2])
In [523]: u2vec(a,v,w)
Out[523]: 
array([array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
       array([-0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]),
       array([ -1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,   0.00000000e+00])], dtype=object)
```