# Using numpy.vecotrize correctly

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm struggling with this code snippet using [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
def to_homogenous(x):
'''
Convert a point x to homogenous coordinates.
'''
return np.hstack((x,np.array([1]))).flatten()

vec_to_homo = np.vectorize(to_homogenous)
coords = vec_to_homo([0,1])
```

This results in the following Error:

> ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 coords1 = vec_to_homo([0,1])
>
> /home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>      2753             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
>      2754
>   -> 2755         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
>      2756
>      2757     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):
>
> /home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
>      2832
>      2833             if ufunc.nout == 1:
>   -> 2834                 res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
>      2835             else:
>      2836                 res = tuple([array(x, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=t)
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I understand the error message but I cannot for the life of me find how I should change my function/the call to vectorize to solve this problem.
The function yields correct results if I pass only a single integer, i.e. `vec_to_homo(0)` yields `[0,1]`.

My snippet is very close to the example provided in the documentation linked above, so I really don't get what is going wrong.

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't say what you expect the `vectorized` result to be.  To work with a function that returns an array, `vectorize` either needs `otypes=[object]` or a `signature` parameter.  And passing anything other than scalars to your function requires the `signature`.  Overall `vectorize` is an awkward crutch - occasionally useful, but easy to misuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors). `np.vectorize` is only appropriate for functions that map floats to floats, not floats to Numpy arrays.

Additionally, `np.vectorize` does not speed up code execution. You can create your own logic inside the function to process a list and return a 2D array using comprehension, looping or similar.