# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

This is a simple example of the big array

```
   x = [[[1,2,3], "abs"], [[1,2,3], "abs"]]
   y = np.array(x)
   z = y[:, 0]
   z.astype('int') # This will throw an error
```

**Output**

> z >> Out[9]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)

is there any way I can convert this from object to int without doing iteration over list x

Comment: Try `np.vstack(z)`.

Comment: sounds good. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for your problem and came across: [Using Numpy Vectorize on Functions that Return Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors).

So I guess you could use a vectorized approach:

```
import numpy as np
x = [[[1,2,3], "abs"], [[1,2,3], "abs"]]
y = np.array(x)
z = y[:, 0]
def f(l):
    return np.array(l)

v = np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(n)')
k = v(z)
```

which gives `k` as:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

---

@hpaulj also suggests a neater method using `np.vstack(z)`, which gives the same answer.

According to the documentation, the argument to vstack should be a "sequence of ndarrays", so I don't think it's strictly correct to pass a sequence of lists, but I can confirm that it does work.

---

Finally, if it were my code I would just stick to a simple list comprehension, it is the simplest way and any solution will have to do some form of for-loop converting lists to ndarrays, so why not just do the iteration in Python.

```
>>> np.array([r[0] for r in x])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Both solutions are cool and np.vstack() also works even if it is sequence of list

Comment: @SACHINGURUSWAMY No problem.