# Vectorize list returning python function into numpy nd-array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I vectorize a pure python function returning a `D`-fixed size list, such that when its applied on `N` data points in a numpy array, it returns a nd-array?

For example, if my python function is as follows, simply applying the vectorized function returns a 1D array of python lists.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.array(["foo", "foo bar baz", "", "zoo"])

>>> def fn(txt: str) -> list:
        size = len(txt)
        return [size - 1, size, size + 1]  # just for show

>>> v_fn = np.vectorize(fn, otypes=[object])

>>> v_fn(data)
array([list([2, 3, 4]), list([10, 11, 12]), list([-1, 0, 1]),
       list([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

& what I'd like instead is for `v_fn(data)` to return a `(4, 3)` shaped numpy array but without having to explicitly do so at the callers like this:

```py
>>> np.array([lst for lst in v_fn(data)])
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
```

Comment: Are you aware that `np.vectorize()` doesn't actually _vectorize_ anything. It simply allows you to broadcast the function over your input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Numpy Vectorize on Functions that Return Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors) Define a wrapper that returns a `ndarray` instead of a list, i.e. `def fn2(txt): return np.array(fn(txt))`. Then `np.vectorize(fn2, signature='()->(n))`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that & hoping answers focus mostly on how to `vectorize` or `frompyfunc` with functions returning fixed-sized python lists.

Comment: Nice @PranavHosangadi! Might there be a way not to need the wrapper function?

Comment: Not that I know of.